# MVC Bootstrap DatePicker shows shadows on load

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using MVC with Boostrap DatePicker. 
I have a simple page to test it.

```
<input type='text' class="form-control datetimepicker1" />
```

I have an usual jQuery function like this:

```js
$(function () {
    var date = new Date();
    $('.datetimepicker1').datepicker({
        format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
        weekStart: 1,
        clearBtn: true,
        showTodayButton: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        autoclose: true,
        forceParse: false,
        calendarWeeks: true,
        startDate: date,
    });
});
```

the `.ui-datepicker` is the same defined in jQuery.

```css
width: 17em;
padding: .2em .2em 0;
display: none;
```

When I load the page, it appears a box shadows that disappear when datepicker get focus.

Where that shadows came from? How can I make it disappear?

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the code in action where the shadow is appearing? Probably the only way anyone can troubleshoot this effectively.

Comment: Thanks... I do not what was happening... but it disappear. Maybe it was the cache of an old style.